# Is Addenbrooke's site/Site a proper noun?

Tags: grammaticality, capitalization

Is [Addenbrooke's site/ Addenbrooke's Site](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Addenbrooke%27s_Hospital&oldid=467497309#The_Addenbrooke.27s_Site) a proper noun or not?

I think the answer depends on the context. The title of the article is *Addenbrooke's Hospital*, supposedly a proper noun. For instance, would *Addenbrooke's Site* be a synonym for *Addenbrooke's Hospital* and would a synonym also be a proper noun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While *Addenbrooke* is a proper noun, *Addenbrooke's site* is not; see previous answer.  In the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addenbrooke%27s_Hospital#The_Addenbrooke.27s_Site)  you link to, *Site* is capitalized when it appears in a title, **The Addenbrooke's Site**, but not when it appears in the sentence after the title:

> In recent years, the Addenbrooke's site has almost become a self-contained town.

***Edit:*** Whether *Addenbrooke's Site* or *site* is a proper noun is not made clear in the sources I've looked at.  On the "No" side:  The Addenbrooke's Hospital [webpage](http://www.cuh.org.uk/addenbrookes/addenbrookes_index.html) does not refer to *Addenbrooke's Site* at all; its [map page](http://www.cuh.org.uk/cuh/finding_us/maps.html) says "However, the Addenbrooke's site is very large and complex"; and Cambridge University's [Addenbrooke's](http://www.admin.cam.ac.uk/univ/disability/guide/sites/addsite.html) page has ten instances of *site* in lowercase, as for example "The site is rather large, but generally very accessible" and "Addenbrooke's is a smoke-free site..."  On the "Yes" side:  The Cambridge page has a main title *Addenbrooke's Site* and a note, "The information on this page is the responsibility of Addenbrooke's Site."

Comment: The house standard on Wikipedia is to use sentence casing in section titles; from [MOS:HEAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style#Section_headings): "The provisions in Article titles (above) generally apply to section headings as well (for example, headings are in sentence case, not title case).". The current content of the Wikipedia article is inconsistent, hence the question.

Comment: @PeterMortensen - The links I added in *Edit* include Addenbrooke's telephone numbers you could call and ask. :)

Answer (score 3):

If the name of the site is "Addenbrooke's Site", then it is a proper noun. If the site has some other name, but it happens to be run by some person or organization called Addenbrooke, then that is not the proper name, but a description. (In which case the "s" in site would be small.)

That is, if Fred Stover opens a grocery store and calls it "Meat and Fish Mart", then "Meat and Fish Mart" is a proper noun, and "Stover's grocery store" is not a proper noun, but a description. But if he calls it, "Stover's Grocery Store", then that is a proper noun which just happens to be descriptive.